# React Carousal renders transparent images with a black background

Tags: css, reactjs

I've a div with transparent background, this is rendered with a black background when I use, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel

How can I modify the CSS to remove the black background?

Comment: Needs more information I'm afraid. Please provide code samples, things that you've tried, screenshots. This isn't enough for us to help.

Answer (score 2):

You should overwrite the css like this:

```
<!-- add a outer class to parent div -->
<div className="carousel-outer">
   <Carousel  ...>
</div>
```

And add these code to css like below:

```
.carousel-outer .carousel .slide {
    background: none;
}
```

Specially designated css has priority over others.